# Angular Issue When clicking on a filtered data from Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, crud

I am facing an issue that I can't solve by myself.

I have an angular firebase where I save some data as follow :
[image]

I added some code to filter by Date "dateDepart"

When I don't use my filter, the information from firebases display just fine.

But when I use the filter (ex: Thu May 27) and click on the date filtered, The information displayed are the ones from "Thu Feb 18".

I know where it comes from :

As you can see in my book-list.component.html :

```
    <button
          class="list-group-item"
          *ngFor="let book of books; let i = index"
          (click)="onViewBook(i)">
Some informations ...
    </button>
```

You can see that the button is clicked depending on the index.

```
  onViewBook(id:number) {
    this.router.navigate(['/books', 'view', id]);
  }
```

When I filter on index 1 (May Thu 27) The index is now "0" so the information displayed is the one from index 0 and not index 1.

Just for you to help me here is my component when i click on the data filteted, single-book.component.ts :

```
 ngOnInit() {
       this.book = new Book(<any>[],'','',''); 
       const id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
       this.booksService.getSingleBook(+id).then(
      (book:Book) => {
        console.log('book', book);
        this.book = book;
      }
    );
```

and the code of getSingleBook(+id) into my cooks.component.ts :

```
  getSingleBook(id: number) {
    return new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
      firebase.database().ref('/books/' + id).once('value').then(
        (data: DataSnapshot) => {
          resolve(data.val());
          console.log("DaTAVAL: ", data.val());
        }, (error) => {
          reject(error);
        }
      );
    }
  );
  }
```

Moreover, you see on my localhost with the snippet tool of firefox, the information below.

Before filter datas :

[image]

After Filter datas :

[image]

I hope it is clear enough for you to understand and help me solve this issue because I am now out of ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Well i got no answer so i finaly found how to solve this issue. I post answer here if people have the same issue :

In book-list-component.ts I changed:

```
  <button
          class="list-group-item"
          *ngFor="let book of books"
          (click)="onViewBook(book.id)">
Some informations ...
    </button>
```

Then in onViewBook i changed:

```
 onViewBook(id:string) {
    this.router.navigate(['/books', 'view', id]);
  }
```

In single-book-component.ts In ngOnInit, I have now :

```
 this.booksService.getSingleBook(id).then(
  (book:Book) => {
    console.log('book', book);
    this.book = book;
    this.index = Object.keys(this.book);
    this.book = this.book[this.index[0]]
  }
);
```